# Name resolution in nodejs or why no errors on name conflicts in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have just started nodejs and following a video tutorial series on Lynda.com and after finishing few sessions, I have the following question :

When I write

```
var softly = function softly(message){
console.log('proclaiming : '+message);
};

var loudly = function loudly(message){
    console.log('PROCLAIMING : '+message);
};

exports.softly = softly;
exports.loudly = loudly;
```

How the mapping of property softly `exports.softly = softly;` is happening, as there is a variable as well as a function with name `softly`?

Comment: No, there are not two variables with the same name. `softly` points to a function named `softly`. If you change the reference, say `softly = 'x'` then you'll loose access to the function too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named function expressions with matching variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333428/named-function-expressions-with-matching-variable-name)

Comment: you are adding a property to `exports` object. It could have been `exports.sth = softly` but for name consistency you are doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function and variable with the same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057649/function-and-variable-with-the-same-name)

Comment: So basically you need to read about function and variable hoisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var softly = function softly(message){
  console.log('proclaiming : '+message);
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
var softly = function (message){ 
  console.log('proclaiming : '+message);
};
```

which is also equivalent to

```
function softly(message){
   console.log('proclaiming : '+message);
};
```

so yes there is function with the name softly created (a function is a variable in javascript ) which is assigned to the same variable. The declaration seems to be redundant, I dont' know there write it like this.

Comment: in fairness only first and last are equivalents.